# Inject already loaded global objects into ActiveRecord preloads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, preload

We have a database with many tables whose data is owned by individual users. All these tables have a `user_id` column that references our `users` table.

When preloading data from these tables we often forget or omit preloading `:user` as it is often unnecessary, repetitive and verbose, as most requests deal with just one user.

We avoid performance problems here by enabling caching, but this blows up our logs with cached select queries for the user, and overall just feels a little incorrect.

I believe a better approach would be to tell ActiveRecord to automatically associate `:user` to our global `User.current` preloaded model, if an explicit preload of `:user` was not requested and if the ids match. Is this possible, with say a prehook into `Model.preload()` somehow?